# Determine maximum width a DOM element might grow to be?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, layout, width

I'm interested in querying the maximum size that a DOM element in a browser might grow to be.  It is well known that an empty DOM element (without styling) has .clientWidth of 0, but adding text/images/etc. to the element might cause its width to grow.  Take for instance the DOM element `thisOne` in the structure below:

```
<table style="padding: 20px; border-spacing: 100px">
   <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td>
            <div id="thisOne"></div>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Currently `#thisOne.clientWidth === 0` but if I append a large amount of text to it, its width will grow and grow, but not until it reaches `document.body.clientWidth` because of the columns, padding classes, etc.  I am wondering how I can figure out the current maximum width of the object without doing something like:

```
const thisOne = document.getElementById('thisOne');
thisOne.style.visibility = 'hidden';  // do not display to user.
thisOne.innerHTML = 'blah '.repeat(2000);
const maxWidth = thisOne.clientWidth;
thisOne.innerHTML = '';
thisOne.style.visibility = 'visible';
```

JQuery based answers are fine, though knowing a pure HTML/JS version would be better.

(In case anyone's wondering, I'm planning on placing an SVG of music notation into the div, but I want it to have nice wrapping onto additional lines by giving the renderer a width to fit before adding it)

Comment: checking its parent's width is in this case is much easier (mind padding)

Comment: thanks.  Changing from bootstrap classes to an embedded table to make the answer more like my real situation.

Comment: okay, you cannot add margins to a td but you can set border-spacing on the table element btw ;)

Comment: Thanks again for the fix.  If I'm asking a question I should be really precise.  (and I know that `'. '.repeat(2000)` gets more accurate reading than `'blah '` but I'm trying NOT to work this way. :-)  )

Comment: U can use flex layout.

Comment: "use flex layout" -- only if I had control of the layout of the rest of the page.  In the case I'm working with, the element could be embedded anywhere on any type of page.  The caller cannot restructure the rest of the page to fit its needs.

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is to set the width of the table to `100%` (so it takes all the available space of the container). Set the desired width of the other columns (`<td>`), either fixed or %. And set the width of the column containing `#thisOne` to `100%`, it will span to the remaining space available (`<div>` is a block, so it will use the whole width by default).

```
<table style="padding: 20px; border-spacing: 100px; width: 100%">
   <tr>
       <td style="width: 100px"></td>
       <td style="width: 100%">
            <div id="thisOne"></div>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Now, `#thisOne` will take all the available space and you can get it's width with `#thisOne.clientWidth`.

If you don't want `#thisOne` to take the whole width by default (i.e., when it's empty), you can simply not set his container `td` width to `100%` and do it by code before you get the `#thisOne.clientWidth` (but you will have to get the `clientWidth` in a `setTimeout` because the browser needs to compute the layout before the `clientWidth` is changed).

As `小聪聪到此一游` pointed out, you can also use `display: flex` and `flex-grow` to achieve the same goal.

```
<div style="display: flex">
    <div style="flex-grow: 0"></div>
    <div style="flex-grow: 1" id="thisOne"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I should explain that changing the layout of other elements on the page besides the one being queried is not a possibility, since the DIV might be embedded in any type of layout.

Comment: Well, the only thing I see then is to programmaticaly set the css style `width` of the parents (`.parentNode()`), one-by-one to the root, to `fill-available` (note that it's an experimental css propertly, so you'll have to use prefixes to satisfy every browser).

Comment: Thanks for the answers and comments -- I'm taking from all of this that this is still no way to figure out this size without changing the styles of parent nodes except by filling the element up with text and measuring it.

Comment: YW. When you think about it, this is quite logical. Take this analogy: while you stay in the room of a house, you can not know the length of that house unless you know that the room takes all the length of the house.

Comment: I like the analogy, but I'm not sure that it works -- if I add lots of furniture to my room, suddenly my room expands, and if I add more furniture, it expands some more, and the house expands with it, but if I keep adding furniture, eventually it stops expanding along with the house.  That's a very odd room!

Comment: My analogy only wanted to show up that, if you have no info about the container, you can not know it's size unless you know that it's content takes the whole space (and it's even harder the more level you have). When you ask JS to give you the potential maximum size of an element, it can't do this without having and computing some information about the level-up containers. So, if you ask JS the potential size of the content, it's like you put an architect in the closed room and ask him "how wide can I expand the room?", he can't know it before he leaves the room.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the easiest way would be to get the width of the parent e.g.
`element.parentNode().clientWidth`

a div will grow only to it's parent element. unless, of course, `white-space: nowrap` is specified.

**EDIT:** this doesn't work

Comment: This doesn't work because the parentNode isn't necessary at its maximum width either.

Comment: but a div element will only grow to max it's parent's width. unless you set a specific value e.g. 120% or 560px

Comment: `<body><div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div></body>` : child.parentNode().clientWidth == 0, but add some text to child and both their widths will grow.